# Parse nested json data in dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have delimited file that have JSON also keyvalues matching in the column. I need to parse this data into dataframe.

Below is the record format

```
**trx_id|name|service_context|status**

abc123|order|type=cdr;payload={"trx_id":"abc123","name":"abs","counter":[{"counter_type":"product"},{"counter_type":"transfer"}],"language":"id","type":"AD","can_replace":"yes","price":{"transaction":1800,"discount":0},"product":[{"flag":"0","identifier_flag":"0","customer_spec":{"period":"0","period_unit":"month","resource_pecification":[{"amount":{"ssp":0.0,"discount":0.0}}]}}],"renewal_flag":"0"}|success
abc456|order|type=cdr;payload={"trx_id":"abc456","name":"abs","counter":[{"counter_type":"product"}],"language":"id","price":{"transaction":1800,"discount":0},"product":[{"flag":"0","identifier_flag":"0","customer_spec":{"period_unit":"month","resource_pecification":[{"amount":{"ssp":0.0,"discount":0.0},"bt":{"service_id":"500_USSD","amount":"65000"}}]}}],"renewal_flag":"1"}|success
```

i need to convert all information from this record to have this format

```
trx_id|name |type|payload.trx_id|payload.name|payload.counter.counter_type|payload.counter.counter_info|.....|payload.renewal.flag|status
abc123|order|cdr |abc123        |abs         |product                     |transfer                    |.....|0                   |success
abc456|order|cdr |abc456        |abs         |product                     |                            |.....|1                   |success
```

Currently i've done manual parsing the data for key_value with **sep=';|[|]** and remove behind '=' and update the column name.
for Json, i do the below command, however the result is replacing the existing table and only contain parsing json result.

```
test_parse = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js)) for js in test_parse['payload']])
```

Is there any way to do avoid any manual process to process this type of data?

Comment: is the problem/query solved?

Comment: not yet, im still searching for the solution.

Comment: Do you need column names to be like this only?

Comment: yes, if possible..

Comment: you need to do it column wise. I have solved the half of it. Try to complete it.

Comment: Is it solved? Did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's realy a 3-step approach

1. use primary pipe | delimiter
2. extract key / value pairs
3. normlize JSON

```
import pandas as pd
import io, json

# overall data structure is pipe delimited
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""abc123|order|type=cdr;payload={"trx_id":"abc123","name":"abs","counter":[{"counter_type":"product"},{"counter_type":"transfer"}],"language":"id","type":"AD","can_replace":"yes","price":{"transaction":1800,"discount":0},"product":[{"flag":"0","identifier_flag":"0","customer_spec":{"period":"0","period_unit":"month","resource_pecification":[{"amount":{"ssp":0.0,"discount":0.0}}]}}],"renewal_flag":"0"}|success
abc456|order|type=cdr;payload={"trx_id":"abc456","name":"abs","counter":[{"counter_type":"product"}],"language":"id","price":{"transaction":1800,"discount":0},"product":[{"flag":"0","identifier_flag":"0","customer_spec":{"period_unit":"month","resource_pecification":[{"amount":{"ssp":0.0,"discount":0.0},"bt":{"service_id":"500_USSD","amount":"65000"}}]}}],"renewal_flag":"1"}|success"""), 
            sep="|", header=None, names=["trx_id","name","data","status"])

df2 = pd.concat([
    df,
    # split out sub-columns ; delimted columns in 3rd column
    pd.DataFrame(
        [[c.split("=")[1] for c in r] for r in df.data.str.split(";")],
        columns=[c.split("=")[0] for c in df.data.str.split(";")[0]], 
    )
], axis=1)

# extract json payload into columns.  This will leave embedded lists as these are many-many
# that needs to be worked out by data owner
df3 = pd.concat([df2, 
           pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(json.loads(p)).add_prefix("payload.") for p in df2.payload]).reset_index()], axis=1)
```

### output

```
    trx_id  name    data    status  type    payload index   payload.trx_id  payload.name    payload.counter payload.language    payload.type    payload.can_replace payload.product payload.renewal_flag    payload.price.transaction   payload.price.discount
0   abc123  order   type=cdr;payload={"trx_id":"abc123","name":"ab...   success cdr {"trx_id":"abc123","name":"abs","counter":[{"c...   0   abc123  abs [{'counter_type': 'product'}, {'counter_type':...   id  AD  yes [{'flag': '0', 'identifier_flag': '0', 'custom...   0   1800    0
```

### use with caution - `explode()` embedded lists

```
df3p = df3["payload.product"].explode().apply(pd.Series)
df3.join(df3.explode("payload.counter")["payload.counter"].apply(pd.Series)).join(
pd.json_normalize(df3p.join(df3p["customer_spec"].apply(pd.Series)).explode("resource_pecification").to_dict(orient="records"))
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. it's almost solved my problem. just need to find a way how to extract counter and product column.

Comment: for embedded lists the logic of how you want to handle needs to be defined.  `explode()` expands an embedded list,  there are two so you need to define rules.  plus your embedded lists are `dict` so those need to be extracted using `pd.Series` or `pd.json_normalize()`.  updated answer with an example - but it's probably incorrect as no data rules have been used

Answer (score 1):

The below hint will be sufficient to solve the problem.

Do it partwise for each column and then merge them together (you will need to remove the columns once you are able to split into multiple columns):

```
import ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
x = json_normalize(df3['service_context'].apply(lambda x: (ast.literal_eval(x.split('=')[1])))).add_prefix('payload.')
```

---

```
y = pd.DataFrame(x['payload.counter'].apply(lambda x:[i['counter_type'] for i in x]).to_list())
y = y.rename(columns={0: 'counter_type', 1:'counter_info'})
```

---

```
for row in x['payload.product']:    
    z1 = json_normalize(row)
    z2 = json_normalize(z1['customer_spec.resource_pecification'][0])
    ### Write your own code.
```

---

**x:**

[image]

**y:**

[image]